Canonical Decomposition in Abelian Categories
Given an abelian category $\mathcal{A}$ and a morphism $f \colon A \to B$ in $\mathcal{A}$, I want to prove the existence of an epimorphism $p_f \colon A \to \operatorname{im} f$ and a monomorphism $i_f \colon \operatorname{im} f \to B$ such that $f = i_f \circ p_f$. Now, I alredy did most of the work but I'm having trouble finishing the proof.
Defining $\operatorname{im} f = \operatorname{coker}(\ker f)$ take $p_f \colon A \to \operatorname{im} f$ as the cokernel map of the kernel $\phi \colon \ker f \to A$. We know, since coequalizer maps are always epimorphisms, that $p_f$ is epi. Now, since $f \circ \phi = 0$, then $B$ is a candidate for the cokernel of $\phi$, hence there is a unique morphism $i_f \colon \operatorname{im} f \to B$ such that $f = i_f \circ p_f$.
The problem here is that I have no clue on how to prove that $i_f$ is mono. I tried proving that its kernel is a zero object, that it can be cancelled on the left, but nothing is working.
For reference: my definition of an abelian category goes the

pre additive $\to$ additive $\to$ pre-abelian $\to$ abelian

route.

This question is exactly dual to: Factoring morphisms in abelian categories - does that help? If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

$\newcommand{\coker}{\operatorname{coker}}$A small point about terminology: what you call image should slightly preferably be called coimage. Cokernels and kernels are not just objects, they are morphisms. $\mathrm{coim}(f):=\coker(\ker f):A\to\mathrm{Coim}(f)$, and $\mathrm{im}(f):=\ker(\coker f):\mathrm{Im}(f)\to B$, and $f$ factors as $\mathrm{im}(f)\circ\gamma\circ\mathrm{coim}(f)$ for some $\gamma:\mathrm{Coim}(f)\to\mathrm{Im}(f)$. Depending on how exactly you defined Abelian category, it is either provable, or definitionally true, that these maps $\gamma$ are always isomorphisms

In my own notes I tend to try to distinguish between $\mathrm{Ke}$ a kernel object and $\ker$ the kernel morphism. I sometimes forget to do so, but it tends to be helpful
